# Separating header and merging part files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge dataframe that is being saved in HDFS with the options header="true" in Scala

This creates multiple part files each having the header and when I merge using `hadoop fs -getmerge` , it creates a single file with multiple headers in it. I can use awk and remove these header files but its not good practice.

Is there a way to write the header files to a separate file for example `_header.csv` and then write the dataframe without the header in the same folder and then merge everything together using `hadoop fs -getmerge`?

I thought of creating a separate tab separated header using `sc.parallelize(Seq(<dataframe>.columns.mkString(“\t"))).saveAsTextFile(<filename>)` but this too creates a part file that needs to be moved to another folder before I merge all the files together